# Definite integral concerning the greatest integer function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Evaluate the integral $$I=\int_{0}^{x} \lfloor t+1 \rfloor^3 dt$$where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

The answer is given as $$\Bigg[\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor(\lfloor x \rfloor +1)}{2}\Bigg]^2+(\lfloor x \rfloor+1)^3 \{x\}$$ where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.

What I have done so far is this:

I used the property $\lfloor x+a \rfloor = a+\lfloor x \rfloor$ where $a$ is a positive integer and expanded the binomial.

$\int_{0}^{x}\lfloor t+1 \rfloor^3 dt = \int_{0}^{x} \lfloor t \rfloor^3 dt + 3\int_{0}^{x} \lfloor x \rfloor^2 dt + 3\int_{0}^{x} \lfloor x \rfloor dt + \int_{0}^{x} dt$

Where

$\int_{0}^{x}\lfloor t \rfloor^3 dt = \int_{1}^{2} 1 dt + \int_{2}^{3} 2^3 dt + \cdots +\int_{\lfloor x \rfloor -1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor}(\lfloor x \rfloor -1)^3+\int_{\lfloor x \rfloor}^{x}\lfloor x\rfloor^3 dt=\Big[\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor(\lfloor x \rfloor -1)}{2}\Big]^2 + \lfloor x \rfloor^3 \{x\} $

$\int_{0}^{x}\lfloor t \rfloor^2 dt = \int_{1}^{2} 1 dt + \int_{2}^{3} 2^2 dt + \cdots +\int_{\lfloor x \rfloor -1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor}(\lfloor x \rfloor -1)^2+\int_{\lfloor x \rfloor}^{x}\lfloor x\rfloor^2 dt=\lfloor x \rfloor^2(\lfloor x \rfloor -1) + \lfloor x \rfloor ^2 \{x\} $

And $\int_0^{x} \lfloor t \rfloor dt = \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor (\lfloor x\rfloor -1)}{2} + \lfloor x \rfloor\{x\}$

Therefore $$I=\Big[\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor(\lfloor x \rfloor -1)}{2}\Big]^2 + \lfloor x \rfloor^3 \{x\} + 3(\lfloor x \rfloor^2(\lfloor x \rfloor -1) + \lfloor x \rfloor ^2 \{x\}) + 3 \Big(\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor (\lfloor x\rfloor -1)}{2} + \lfloor x \rfloor\{x\}\Big)+x$$

But I am having trouble in reducing it further. I might be missing something, I am sorry about that. Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to OP's stated answer we have
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\int_{0}^{x} \lfloor t+1 \rfloor^3\,dt=\left(\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor(\lfloor x \rfloor +1)}{2}\right)^2+(\lfloor x \rfloor+1)^3 \{x\}}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

This can be shown as follows
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{x}\lfloor t+1\rfloor ^3\,dt&=\int_{1}^{x+1}\lfloor u\rfloor ^3\,du\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor}j^3+\int_{\lfloor x\rfloor+1}^{x+1}\lfloor u\rfloor ^3\,du\tag{3}\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{2}\lfloor x\rfloor\left(\lfloor x\rfloor+1\right)\right)^2+\left(\lfloor x\rfloor+1\right)^3\left\{x\right\}
\end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we substitute $t+1=u, dt=du$ and arrange the limits accordingly.
- In (3) we use the same representation as in OPs post regarding $\int_{0}^{x}\lfloor t \rfloor^3 dt$.

> We  can   also show the result (1) using OPs calculation, with  the  correction regarding $\int_{0}^{x}\lfloor t \rfloor^2 dt$
>   \begin{align*}
> \int_{0}^{x}\lfloor t \rfloor^3 dt
> &=\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor-1}j^3\int_{j}^{j+1}\,dt+\lfloor x\rfloor^3\{x\}\\
> &=\left(\frac{1}{2}\lfloor x\rfloor\left(\lfloor x\rfloor-1\right)\right)^2+\lfloor x\rfloor^3\{x\}\tag{4}\\
> \int_{0}^{x}\lfloor t \rfloor^2 dt
> &=\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor-1}j^2\int_{j}^{j+1}\,dt+\lfloor x\rfloor^2\{x\}\\
> &=\frac{1}{6}\left(\lfloor x\rfloor-1\right)\lfloor x\rfloor\left(2\lfloor x\rfloor-1\right)+\lfloor x\rfloor^2\{x\}\tag{5}\\
> \int_{0}^{x}\lfloor t \rfloor dt
> &=\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor-1}j\int_{j}^{j+1}\,dt+\lfloor x\rfloor\{x\}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\lfloor x\rfloor\left(\lfloor x\rfloor-1\right)+\lfloor x\rfloor\{x\}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
>
> With (4)-(6) we obtain     according to OPs   calculation
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\int_{0}^{x}\lfloor t+1 \rfloor^3 dt}
> &= \int_{0}^{x} \lfloor t \rfloor^3 dt + 3\int_{0}^{x} \lfloor x \rfloor^2 dt + 3\int_{0}^{x} \lfloor x \rfloor dt + \int_{0}^{x}\,dt\\
> &=\left(\frac{1}{2}\lfloor x\rfloor\left(\lfloor x\rfloor-1\right)\right)^2+\lfloor x\rfloor^3\{x\}\\
> &\qquad +3\left(\frac{1}{6}\left(\lfloor x\rfloor-1\right)(\lfloor x\rfloor\left(2(\lfloor x\rfloor-1\right)+\lfloor x\rfloor^2\{x\}\right)\\
> &\qquad +3\left(\frac{1}{2}\lfloor x\rfloor\left(\lfloor x\rfloor-1\right)+\lfloor x\rfloor\{x\}\right) \\
> &\qquad +\lfloor x\rfloor+\{x\}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{4}\lfloor x\rfloor ^4+\frac{1}{2}\lfloor x\rfloor ^3+\frac{1}{4}\lfloor x\rfloor ^2+(\lfloor x \rfloor+1)^3 \{x\}}
> \end{align*}
>   corresponding to the claim  in (1).

Comment: Thank you. I've corrected the typo.

Comment: @alphasquared: You're welcome.